# Вопрос по работе с свойствами класса

Tags: php, ооп, классы, атрибуты

Здравствуйте, хочу реализовать одну вещь, суть ее в следующем: Есть класс `А`, в нем метод `method` и свойство `atribute` и файл, например `index.php`.
В файле создается экземпляр класса `А`.

```
$object = new A();
$object->method();
```

Однако мне нужно, чтобы свойство я мог получить только после вызова этого метода, т.е. IDE мне подсказывает, что я могу после `$object->` выбрать ИЛИ `$atribute` ИЛИ `method();` Нужно, чтобы `$atribute` я мог получить ТОЛЬКО после вызова `method()`, например:

`$object->method()->atribute;`.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Что-то мне не верится, что IDE до такого "додумается" :)

Comment: Додумается, просто их как-то надо подгрузить. Подобная штука есть у ReflectionClass и Instagram Private API. Фишка в том, что есть атрибуты и объект возвращается с такими же ключами, как и имена этих атрибутов. Т.е. у ReflectionClass, например, после вызова $obj->getProperties(); возвращается объект, список свойств определенного класса. И есть ключ name. После вызова метода, доступ можно потом вывести только name и IDE это "подгружает". Например: $obj->getProperties()->name; И в ReflectionClass есть свойство $name.

Comment: Так может метод возвращает ссылку на другой класс в котором доступны нужные свойства? И IDE об этом знает?

Comment: Хм, вполне может быть... А можно пример кода, как ссылку на другой класс вернуть?

Comment: `return new OtherClass();` ?

Comment: Вроде оно, а вроде и нет. Свойство все равно можно вызвать ДО метода, но оно уже не помечается, как "активное" :/

Comment: если в классе объявлено паблик свойство, то к нему можно обратится когда угодно. вы с этим вообще ничего сделать не сможете в принципе.

Comment: Да, но мне кажется эта фишка работает немного по другому. Например: Есть объект:
stdClass Object (
    [name] => Alex
)

name можно получить $object->method()->name; Но IDE это "подсвечивать" не будет. Как вариант - создать в классе свойство $name, и проинициализировать: $this->name = $object->method()->name; 
Но это свойство потом можно будет вызвать везде, и ДО вызова метода тоже :/

Comment: Не думаю, что вообще то, что Вы хотите сделать - что-то хорошее или полезное. Для чего выставлять для себя ограничения какие-то?

Answer (score 2):

не претендует на ответ, но то что вы описываете обычно выглядит примерно так:

```
class InnerA {
    public $name = "namenamename";
}


class A {

    private $inner = null;


    public function myMethod(){
        if(!$this->inner){
            $this->inner = new InnerA();
        }
         return $this->inner;
    }
}


$a = new A();
print $a->myMethod()->name;
```

Если вы объявите публичное свойство `$name` в класса `A`, то ничто и никто не помешает обратиться к нему, раньше чем к какому-то методу, как вы говорите.
На этапе выполнения, вы конечно можете это контролировать создав исключение при нежелательном доступе, но на этапе разработки это не возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
class A
{

    public $atribute;

    protected function method() 
    {
        $this->atribute = "Hello, World";

        return $this->atribute
    }

}

class B extends A
{

    protected $test;

    public function test()
    {

        $this->test = new A();
        $this->test->method();

        return $this->test;
    }
}

$object = new B();
$object->test->test()->atribute;
```

Comment: мне почему-то кажется, что вы не особо понимаете, что происходит в этом коде.